# AVAudioPlayer delegate wont get called in a class method?

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, avaudioplayer

i am using the AVAudioPlayer and setting its delegate but its delegate is not getting called

```
      + (void) playflip
        {
        NSString *path;
        path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"flip" ofType:@"mp3"];
        AVAudioPlayer *flip;
        flip = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:Nil];
        flip.delegate = self;
        [flip play];
}
```

My class where i am implementing is the sound class

```
  @interface    SoundClass : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

I am calling this delegate

```
    - (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"delegate called");
    [player release];
    player = nil;
}
```

Comment: Did you try just `flip.delegate = self;` ? I don't cast when I do this.

Comment: yes i tried that but its not getting called..it showed up some warning though, it said incompatible pointer types assigning to <id>AVAudioPlayerDelegate from class

Comment: the sounds are getting played though, but the delegate is only not called

Comment: But i am using it in a class method?? is that wrong?? not an instance method

Comment: The only thing I can see is maybe that your `flip` object is defined inside the scope of the function. Is it getting lost? I'll post an answer with what my code looks like (and works).

Comment: thanks matt, but i am sure that i am not getting it lost its within the scope only

Comment: Ahh, a class method and not an interface method, gotcha. My answer is an interface method.

Comment: k matt, thank you so much for ur reply, but is there any method to do this??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like maybe your `flip` object is going out of scope, because the rest of your code looks fine. Here's what I do:

```
// controller.h
@interface    SoundClass : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate> {}
// @property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary *sounds;
// I have lots of sounds, pre-loaded in a dictionary so that I can reference by name
// With one player, you can just use:
@property(nonatomic,retain) AVAudioPlayer *player;
```

Then allocate and load the sound in your .m

```
player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:Nil];
[player prepareToPlay];
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
```

Now you should get your `DidFinishPlaying` notification.

Comment: i am doing same thing but after playing audio app is crash and delegate method is not called